# vb.net datagridview with dataset as datasource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

my question is, is there a way to filter records in the dataset and use that records to fill in the datagridview? for example, a datatable (with 3 columns: `ID`, `StudentName`, `Gender`) is filled with list of students. i have two datagrids in the form namely `DatagridView1` and `Datagridview2`. `DatagridView1` is where the the list of student where `Gender` is equal to `M` and `DatagridView2` is where the the list of student where `Gender` is equal to `F`.

in my current solution, i am using a loop.

```
For each iStud as datarow in iDataset.Tables(0).Rows
      IF iStud.Item("Gender").ToString = "M" Then
            'add this record to DatagridView1
      Else
            'add this record to DatagridView2
      End If
Next
```

is there a way without using a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. All you need to do is to filter the dataset using `SELECT`.

For example,

```
DatagridView1.Datasource = xSet.Tables("StudentList").SELECT("Gender = 'M'")
DatagridView2.Datasource = xSet.Tables("StudentList").SELECT("Gender = 'F'")
```

Brief Explanation:

```
xSet          is the name of the Dataset
StudentList   is the name of the Datatable
Gender        is the name of the Column where you want to filter
```

**UPDATE**

[image: Screen Shot]